# extract a date from a STRING ROBOT FRAMEWORK

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

${my-string} "Fête : Anniversaire

Emplacement : Paris

Date  : 08/12/2021

Prix : texte"

I need to extract the date from this text but i can't end up with a solution using robot framework , i tried :

```
${REGULAR EXPRESSION}    \d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
Get Regexp Matches    ${my-string}    ${REGULAR EXPRESSION}
```

But it gave me null as a result , any solution for that please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think because in Python/Robot Framework the backslash is treated as am escape character, you need an additional backslash on each occassion you use it in your reg ex

e.g. `\\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}`

So something like this should work:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  String

*** Test Cases ***
Check Date Regex
   ${date}     Set Variable  Fête : Anniversaire Emplacement : Paris Date : 08/12/2021 Prix : texte
   ${regex}    Set Variable  \\d{2}\\/\\d{2}\\/\\d{4}
   ${matches}  Get Regexp Matches  ${date}  ${regex}

   ${match}  Set Variable  ${NONE}
   IF  ${matches}
       ${match}  Set Variable  ${matches}[0]
   END
   log to console  ${match}
```

With output:

```
08/12/2021
```

Comment: thanks for ur reponse but i need the result to be only in the format 08/12/2021 ??

Comment: @faith I've done an edit to make it a bit safer and with the format you expect